# VBA exception handling fail?

Tags: vba, outlook, windows-7, outlook-2010

I have created this script to play a wav file when I receive an email.  The point is to play the sound only during business hours.  If the email is received outside business hours, no sound will play.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Sub PlayWavFile(WavFileName As String, Wait As Boolean)
    If Dir(WavFileName) = "" Then Exit Sub ' no file to play
    If Wait Then ' play sound synchronously
        PlaySound WavFileName, 0, 0
    Else ' play sound asynchronously
        PlaySound WavFileName, 0, 1
    End If
End Sub

Sub PlayASoundDuringBusinessHours(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim SecondsSinceMidnight
  Dim SecondsPerHour
  Dim NineOclockAm
  Dim NineOclockPm
  Dim TooEarly
  Dim TooLate

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
  SecondsSinceMidnight = Timer
  SecondsPerHour = 60 * 60
  NineOclockAm = SecondsPerHour * 9
  NineOclockPm = SecondsPerHour * 21
  TooEarly = Timer < NineOclockAm
  TooLate = Timer > NineOclockPm

  If Not (TooEarly) And Not (TooLate) Then
    PlayWavFile "c:\windows\media\blahblahblah.wav", False
  End If

ExitProcedure:
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, _
    vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, _
    "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number)
    Resume ExitProcedure:
End Sub
```

I have a rule in Outlook that uses this script when mail comes in and it works! For a while, anyway.

I do not know what the problem is, but once in a while an error occurs in this script and I get a dialog from Outlook that says "Rules in error" and "The operation failed."  When this happens, the Outlook rule that uses this script becomes disabled.

Is my exception handling inadequate?  What could be causing this error and how do I handle it properly?

**Update:**

The rule is very basic.  It does little beyond executing the script:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
on this computer only
run Project.PlayASoundDuringBusinessHours
```

Comment: +1. Just as an aside, you can improve your code somewhat. Get rid of `TooEarly` and `TooLate`, and add `OkToPlaySound = (SecondsSinceMidnight > NineOclockAm) And (SecondsSinceMidnight < NineOclockPm)`. You can then change your `If` statement to `If (OkToPlaySound) Then`. (You eliminate one variable, and actually use the `SecondsSinceMidnight` you've already declared and set, and make the `If` statement more readable.) The error may not be in this script, BTW, but may be in the Outlook rule; if it was in the script code, your `MsgBox` should halt it (and Outlook) to display the error dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I have updated the question to provide more detail about the rule.

Comment: You're right. That's a simple rule. :-) Have you checked the Windows Event Log (particularly Application Events) to see if Outlook posted anything? You might also alter your error handler to log the error message instead of using `MsgBox`, which Outlook may be supressing because it would stop Outlook itself from executing until closed.

Comment: On your advice, I looked through the Windows Event Log but didn't find any clues.  I will look into logging the error.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of a rule, why not use the

Application_NewMail

event, and use logic to determine whether to play the sound or not with the code you have in your sub?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct response to the question but my solution was to switch to ItemAdd.

Examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171270(v=office.11).aspx
http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62